# Passing multiple parameter in Url of a web service in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, web-services, ionic-framework

I want to call a url through my service in ionic project.
the url should be like www.helloworld.com/getdetails?a=10&b=20&c=30

the service call is made like this

```
$http({
    method: "POST",
    url:"/getIdeaList",  
    params:{'a':10,'b':20,'c':30},
    headers: {
        'devicemetadata':deviceMetadata,
        'Encoding':"UTF-8",
        'deviceID':deviceID
    }
});

//getIdeaList is proxy for Url-www.helloworld.com/getdetails
```

I tried like the about but the its calling like this-www.helloworld.com/getdetails?a=10& amp;b=20& amp;c=30\n

Comment: So what is wrong? is it the /n?

Comment: there should not be `\n` at the end of URL

Comment: No...when the service will be called internally url should be like www.helloworld.com/getdetails?a=10&b=20&c=30....but its coming like this     www.helloworld.com/getdetails?a=10&amp;b=20&amp;c=30\n...

Comment: Are you positive? You are using the POST method which shouldn't send the params in the URL, but instead through a header. Did you check the Network Monitor in Chrome Dev Tools to see what the request is that is being sent?

Comment: through param attribute we can add parameters at the end of url...i have tried it with one parameter...the problem is coming when i am using multiple parameters..